# Assign 3D object loaded to a variable - return undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, callback

I have written a function to load 3D object with three.js.

I want this function to return the 3D object when loaded but I got undefined whatever I'm doing anyway.

```
function load3DObject(url, meshMaterial) {
  let mesh;
  let url3DObject = url;
  let Object3dMaterial = meshMaterial;

  loader.load(
    url3DObject,
    function(gltf) {
      let ArrowModel = gltf.scene;

      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(ArrowModel, Object3dMaterial);

      mesh.castShadow = true; //default is false

      mesh.receiveShadow = false; //default

      scene.add(mesh);

      scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);

      Objects.push(mesh);
    },
    undefined,

    function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );

  console.log(mesh);

  return mesh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the loader is asynchronous. You call the function load that calls a callback function when it's done but you return the mesh right after and the callback has not done anything yet.
I don't know how you can achieve it properly though, maybe there are some more experienced js developers who can help about it.